# Rails Simple form: Unable to render validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-7

I have an application with 3 models; for all those models, I have used the `simple_form` gem to render the form.

Initially, my goal was to render inline validation messages under their respective fields, and I had never tried that before so I made a google search to find out how it's done, and then I found out about the `simple_form` gem.

So I followed the [RailsCasts tutorial](https://youtu.be/o0eVqNbapb0) and its [GitHub page](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) to set up the gem in my application and used it for all of the models in my application. It was working perfectly fine showing the default error message at the top and the validation message at the bottom of their respective fields.

I also implemented test suites using RSpec and Capybara to check if validation messages show up when a user fills in an invalid detail and it would work as expected.

A couple of days went by and I was continuing to build my application and was running all the test suites every now and then and everything was working as expected. Then for some reason, I manually wanted to create a user with invalid details and expect to show validation messages but it wouldn't. I was completely shocked. I mean it wasn't creating it either but it wasn't showing in the view. I know this because I gave a debugger in the controller to see if it actually passes validation messages and it was. But it just wasn't showing in the view. And this scenario happens to all of the models. It is able to create instances with valid values but not show error messages for invalid ones. And same is true with the RSpec test suites as it expects the message to show but it's not able to find it.

I have been trying to debug this problem for days but have just not been able to. I mean I can give my own code to show-up validations but why isn't it showing now as it was showing then?

I also tried to see if I had implemented any code in the past few days that was interrupting the gems' process somehow. So I browsed through the commit history and checked out the commit where I thought it could have affected to raise this error. But was unlucky in the process. In fact, I went back to that commit where I had initialized the gem, and it still wasn't working.

I also inspected the bootstrap files of simple_form that it installs to see if it's working and it does. I then implemented bootstrap styles to the form and it is working perfectly fine.

I also tried the trick to re-install the gem in case I unintentionally messed up some code in their initializer files. But it didn't work, it just works the same out of the box too.

I would like your help in this, wondering if you have faced such issues. I am just not able to find what is causing the issue, so I can debug it.

If you're curious, I am running the Rails `7.0.4` with Ruby `3.1.2` and simple_form `5.1.0` version with JS (esbuild) & CSS (Bootstrap 5.2)

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

gem "sprockets-rails"

gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

gem "jsbundling-rails"

gem "turbo-rails"

gem "stimulus-rails"

gem "cssbundling-rails"

gem "jbuilder"

gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

gem "bootsnap", require: false


group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem "shoulda-matchers", git: 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

gem 'validates_email_format_of'

gem 'faker'

gem 'friendly_id'

gem "simple_form", "~> 5.1"

gem 'ransack'

gem "humanize", "~> 2.5"
```

My model:

```
<% its_message = "must be exactly 8 characters long" %>
<% mobile_message = "without the country code" %>

<%= simple_form_for @sabeel do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :its, hint: its_message %>
    <%= f.input :hof_name, placeholder: "Shk. Fakruddin Nakhudawala" %>
    <%= f.input :apartment, collection: Sabeel.apartments.keys.map{ |apartment| [apartment.titleize, apartment] }, include_blank: false %>
    <%= f.input :flat_no %>
    <%= f.input :mobile, hint: mobile_message, placeholder: "9876543210" %>
    <%= f.input :email, input_html: { class: "mb-5" }%>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am using the default vertical wrapper for my simple_form, `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` file:

```
  # vertical default_wrapper
  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group col-md-4 offset-md-4 mb-3', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'fw-normal fs-5'
    b.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
    b.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
  end
```

I am not able to find the error class `form-group-invalid` in both simple_form files in the `config/initializers` dir. I don't know if that's necessary, but if it is expected to be given somewhere then where would it be?

Initially, I did say that I used the `simple_form` gem to implement inline validations but after knowing its simplicity and ease of use I want to use `simple_form` only unless there's some other gem that's much better!

Thanks! :)

Comment: You have a long story in this question, which can lead to people skipping it. I suggest shortening your question to just a few sentences and the relevant code.

Comment: Please also include server logs of what happens when you submit an invalid record, but don't get the error messages.